# how to access dynamically added radiobutton in update panel

Tags: c#, updatepanel, postback, radio-button

ive product detail page , ive radiobutton in this page which i created dynamically in an updatepanel because of postback... i created it very well ,  there is an checkedchanged event for all radiobuttons it works very well but i need to get radiobutton text value but i cant reach the radiobutton, it looks as control in updatepanel... but here thing at least for me:D... after i deleted update panel i can reach radiobuttons easily... why it happens like this , i couldnt understand... but i know something i need to prevent page postback on radiobuttons checkedchanged event so how can i do this by using ajax or updatepanel something...

thx...

Answer (score 0):

You said that you can reach radiobutton but it looks like a control. I think you access like that:

```
myUpdatePanel.Controls[0] // or in a foreach or something like that
```

What about cast each of that controls?

```
var myRadioButton = (RadioButton)myUpdatePanel.Controls[0];
```

Comment: thx vitor , but its not the answer , i tried it but it returns as control, when i looked at inside of  updatepanel.contenttemplatecontainer.controls, i found my radiobuttons :D  thx again...